# Selecting elements based on absence of class-attribute in HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using the HTML DOM, I would like to select almost all td tags except for those td tags that have a class-attribute of "xyz".

With document.selectElementsByTagname["td"] I can get all the td-elements. However, I don't want all but only those where the class-attribute != "xyz".

Since there are no predicates in html DOM, I currently don't see a way to achieve this. Is there still a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://www.google.com/search?q=querySelectorAll&oq=querySelectorAll&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class selector.

```
document.querySelectorAll("td:not(.xyz)")
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("td:not(.xyz)")).forEach(function(e) {
  e.style.color = "red";
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="xyz">a</td>
    <td class="xyz">a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td class="xyz">a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td class="xyz">a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do like this:

```
document.querySelector("td:not(.xyz)")
```